# Using input() in a Subprocess in IPython started with %%script py -2

Tags: python, ipython

The following code uses cell magic to run Python 2 in a subprocess in IPython:

```
%%script py -2
print 'foo'
```

It works as expected (i.e., it prints 'foo').

But when I try to get user input in a subprocess, it fails:

```
%%script py -2
input('foo? ')
```

Here's the output:

```
foo? Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any ideas why input won't work in the subprocess?

In case it helps, here's a screen grab:

[image: IPython Python 2 in Subprocess: input() fails]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's something odd with `stdin` in the subprocess (it seems to be closed), so this might bypass that:

```
>>> %%script python
... stdin = open('/dev/tty')
... line = stdin.readline()
... print 'input:', line  # python 2.7.6 is default on my sys
... 
yay!
input: yay!
```

The above is the output when running on IPython 1.2.1, with Python 3.4.0 (with %doctest_mode).

Comment: Thanks, @andré. This does work as you say in the IPython console (not in an IPython Notebook for some reason), but it's not the same as `input()`. My purpose is to demonstrate the difference between how input() works in Python 2 (evaluates input string) and in Python 3 (does not evaluate input string). Also, for others trying this, on Windows, you need to set `stdin` to `open('CON:')`.

Comment: True, this is a hack and not very flexible/portable.